# How do I pass an argument to a stateful widget when my widget uses string id to be referenced?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-layout

In my Flutter app, I'm using const String ids to navigate from screen to screen like so

```
  static const String id = 'onboarding5'; //in onboarding5.dart
  static const String id = 'Sessions';  //in sessions.dart
```

So in my main.dart, I initialized my routes like so

```
  routes { 
    Onboarding4.id: (context) => Onboarding4(),
    Onboarding5.id: (context) => Onboarding5(),
    Sessions.id: (context) => Sessions(),
  },
```

In my Onboarding5 screen, I have 2 buttons;

- Sign Up
- Sign In

Clicking either will navigate user to SessionsScreen. My Sessions class extends stateful widget and uses an enum FormType to toggle view between SignUp and SignIn.

How do I pass the _formType argument from onboarding5 to the Sessions class constructor without changing my current way of routing through screens using static const String id?

Typically, the popular way without declaring a static const String id would have been like so

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sessions');
```

or

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, Sessions());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the optional `arguments` parameter for `pushNamed`

Comment: Thanks. I used it but then I ran into some errors. I can't perform 

widget.formType in my State class;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your `_formType` as an argument. Create a class called 'SignArguments'
which will contain your enum and other information which you might need to pass. You can receive the arguments in `SessionsScreens` using `final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;`

```dart
enum sessionEnum {signUp , signIn}
class SignArguments {
  final sessionEnum sessionType;
  // you can pass other stuffs as well.
  SignArguments(this.sessionType);
}

Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sessions',arguments:SignArguments(sessionEnum.signUp));
```

to receive your arguments

```dart
final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
// now you can access your enum which you have passed.
if (args.sessionType == sessionEnum.signIn) {
  // do something.
}
```

you can read more about arguments here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments.

Comment: hey zeeshan, thanks for showing me this.

I am able to pass the argument, but retrieving/receiving it in my SessionsScreen is not working it seems. I used a print statement to ensure the right sessionEnum type is being passed at each button, but in my Sessions screen/class, I'm unable to read the passed argument.

Also, with your method, I don't seem to need a constructor in my Sessions stateful widget class anymore do I?

Comment: A little issue though, I created two methods, that is called to toggle the view by setting the state  setState(() { _formType = sessionEnum.signUp; }  and setState(() { _formType = sessionEnum.signIN; } 

These are Called when the user clicks on my clickable TextFields. "Already have an account? Sign in here" and "Don't have an account? Sign up now"

The toggle doesn't seem to update the state of my _formType onClick PaddedClikabledText. Any idea why?

Comment: well, I can't tell anything without seeing the full code. you can look for some answers here, otherwise, post a new question and someone will answer.

Comment: Figured it out for anyone else passing through. Be sure to declare a global _formKey like so:   final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); 

Save form every time  a change is made. That's what I was missing.

In code terms: 
final form = _formKey.currentState();
if(form..validate()) {
form.save() }